# Post-back a value from text field that dynamically created [ASP.net]

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, postback

In my webpage i got a button, next to button there is a input type='text' text box that i create dynamically (*so i can't use the runat="server"*)

I wan't to post back what the user has entered in the input box to the server.

This is what i have done:

```
<asp:LinkButton id="xx" OnClick="xx" runat="server">
```

And another button

```
<button onclick="some_js_function()">
```

And the text box that dynamically generated

And Another

```
<aspx:HiddenField>
```

This is what happens:
The aspx button is hidden, when the user clicks the other button the js functions is called and copies the value from the javascript text box the hidden field box and then clicks (jQuery .click() ) the aspx hidden button.

In the Google Chrome console i can see that the post-back is happening, and the value successfully copied but the server-side function that the onclick in the aspx button that is hidden is never called.

This probably not the best way to do this..

If someone got a better idea or a way to fix this i will be happy :)

Comment: Unhide the button and then click it, is event is getting fired? I doubt. You may add the aspx and cs code so some one can debug it

Comment: It does fire, i use this in another page, but now its not working. But i don't like this method.. there must be a nicer way to do this. And i don't Unhide the aspx button, i just use $("<%ASP_BUTTON_NAME.ClientID").click() to trigger it, and the post-back does fires, i can see in the Console "XHR finished loading: POST but nothing happens, the server-side functions is not called (im in debug mode)

Answer (score 1):

Every element in your `form` tag, if its added manually or dynamically, will be posted back to the server.

Manually added inputs eg: `<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtBox"></asp:TextBox>` can be called directly into your backend using:

*SET Text:*

`this.txtBox.Text = "Some Text";`

*GET Text:*

`string valueBox = this.txtBox.Text;`

Dynamically added controls need to be assigned with both `id` and `name` attributes. Example:

`<input type="text" id="txtBox" name="txtBox" />`

Then in your backend you can get the value of the textbox by using [Request.Form](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525985(v=vs.90).aspx):

`string valueBox = Request.Form["txtBox"].ToString();`

Comment: But im not posting the form, i do a post-back.. where will i use Request.Form in the .cs file ?  I know i can access Request.Form but i have a button in the middle of the form that query something from a database and than change another part of the form.